# Create versioned documentation archive

Tags: jekyll

I am in the process of rebuilding a API documentation site for an open source project where we want to keep an archive of previous releases. I am wondering how I can configure Jekyll to generate the right hierarchy?

We have the following directory layout in our current `/docs` folder (which we would like to reuse in Jekyll somehow):

```
current/
v1/
v2/
v3/
```

Whenever we release a new version the `current` folder gets copied to a new folder (say `v4`). The contents of each folder is something like this:

```
introduction.md
testing.md
api-foo.md
api-bar.md
```

I'd like these to be available under the url `domain.com/v3/testing/`, `domain.com/current/testing/`, etc. I see that I could probably employ collections to do this, having one collection per version. To do this I see myself auto-updating the _config.yml as part of a [build script (I made an example doing this here](https://gist.github.com/fatso83/e403f5ee2500487088ab0598e49a7d91)), but I am not sure how to progress from here, or if using collections for this is the wrong approach ...

Answer (score 0):

This is too brief of an update to be of real quality, but thought I would mention that we solved this in the end in the Sinon project. Check out the repo at GitHub sinonjs/sinon and see the docs folder as well as the scripts called from package.json.

Feel free to improve on this answer by editing it and adding content and links.